# Convertir lista de tipo Type a Objeto de clase C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tengo el código:

**Clase Dispositivo:**

```
 public class Dispositivo
    {
        private string codigoDispositivo;

        private string descripion;

        private bool estado;

        public string CodigoDispositivo { get => codigoDispositivo; set => codigoDispositivo = value; }

        public string Descripcion { get => descripion; set => descripion = value; }

        public bool Estado { get => estado; set => estado = value; }


    }
```

**Controlador:**

```
 // GET: api/Dispositivos
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<Dispositivo>> Get()
    {


        using (var sql=new Servicio())
        {
            List<Type> dispositivosType= await sql.cargarDatos(typeof(Dispositivo));


            sql.Dispose();

            return dispositivosType.Cast<Dispositivo>().ToList();
        }


    }
```

**Donde el método cargarDatos me devulve la lista completa de tipo Type que en realidad son los dispositivos**, sin embargo quiero devolver esa lista en un controlador de Web Api net core sin tener que hacer un foreach pero me da error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**En la variable dispositivosType se guarda lo siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Indica el código completo del Controlador **DispositivosController** por favor.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Listo

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los datos que traes en "dispositivosType" y los detalles de la clase "Dispositivo"

Comment: Prueba esto: `return dispositivosType.Cast<Dispositivo>().ToListAsync()`;

Comment: @fredyfx Listo!!

Comment: No esta disponible el método  ToListAsync()!!!!!!!!

Comment: ¿Y lo que hay dentro de la variable "dispositivosType"?

Comment: @fredyfx Listo!!!

Comment: **ToListAsync()** es un método extensor de Entity Framework Core, utilizas Entity Framework Core?

Comment: No , no uso entity framework core en este proyecto.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta No  esa  no es  la razón del error

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez:  No puedes hacer esto: `List<Dispositivo> dispositivosType= await sql.cargarDatos(typeof(Dispositivo))`; y ahorrarte el Cast?. Devolverías: `return dispositivosType.ToList()`;

Comment: Si  fuera así de fácil  .... Ya lo intenté y me pide que el List debe ser tipo Type.  De esa List<Type>  tengo que ver como la convierto a el objeto que yo quiera.

Comment: Hola, al parecer estas devolviendo objetos que no se pueden castear a ese tipo. Por favor, pon el codigo del metodo que devuelve el listado para ayudarte mejor.